# What are the lowest-expense index funds available to an EU citizen?

Tags: investing, index-fund, european-union

I see people talking about [0.05% expense ratios](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/29139/9729), presumably meaning the Vanguard S&P 500 fund. Vanguard advertises an average expense ratio of 0.19%. Sounds great. But the index funds from iShares, DB x-Trackers and Lyxor I see in my bank's funds DB are much more expensive, mostly round 0.5% (even ETFs). And Vanguard is apparently [only available to US residents](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/30286/non-resident-alien-investing-in-a-vanguard-mutual-fund-is-this-allowed).

So which are the cheapest options available in the EU? I'm looking for both specific funds and general information - for example, Vanguard also lists a [0.05% ratio for their S&P 500 ETF](https://advisors.vanguard.com/VGApp/iip/site/advisor/investments/productoverview?fundId=0968) - can I simply by that on an exchange? Would it cause any problems?

Comment: https://www.vanguard.co.uk/uk/portal/portal would be Vanguard's UK site that may be worth noting.

Answer (score 4):

There are many options. For example, [iShares S&P 500 UCITS ETF (Acc)](http://www.ishares.com/de/individual/de/produkte/251901/ishares-sp-500-ucits-etf-acc-fund), ISIN DE000A0YBR61, has a TER of 0.07%.

Vanguard is also available in Europe. See, e.g., https://www.vanguardinvestments.de/ and https://www.vanguard.co.uk/.

PS: iShares has update its product line in Germany and the cost for many iShares core ETFs has been reduced. See http://www.ishares.com/de/individual/de/campaign/core-series/ishares-core-series-page2-ind.

Comment: Interesting information about Vanguard. What's strange though is that my bank's funds database lists that iShares fund with a TER of 0.4% - I'll have to investigate that.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt If I remember correctly, the TER was 0.4%. iShares has reduced it just recently. Many financial websites, e.g., http://www.finanzen.net/etf/iShares_S&P_500_DE_UCITS_ETF_Acc, haven't updated it yet.

Answer (score 3):

The lowest expense ratio among European index funds that I could find is the 0.16% of the iShares DAX (ISIN: DE0005933931).

Answer (score 0):

You can search on, e.g. [Boerse Frankfurt](http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/de/etfs/suche/ergebnis?show_type_nav_bar=0&show_back_button=1&type=etf&default_text=%28Name%2C%20WKN%20oder%20ISIN%29&name_isin_wkn=%28Name%2C%20WKN%20oder%20ISIN%29&product_name=&etf_issuer=&asset_class__wm_vetp=&investment_focus__wm_vetp=&wm_vetp__country=&region__wm_vetp=&sector__wm_vetp=&strategy__wm_vetp=&size__wm_vetp=&long__short__leveraged_long=&benchmark__wm_vetp=&index_family=&index_type=&use_of_profits__wm_vetp=164&replication_type__wm_vetp=&fondsdomizil=&fund_currency=&trading_currency=&quanto=&total_expense_ratio=0.25&swap_collaterized__wm_vetp=&listing_date_etf=&ucits_conformity=&order_by=management_fee_in_percent) for ETFs with low management fees.  Currently, it finds [db x-trackers FTSE 100 UCITS ETF (DR) 1C (LU0838780707)](http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/de/etfs/db+x+trackers+ftse+100+ucits+etf+dr+1c+etf+LU0838780707) or [Source EURO STOXX 50 UCITS ETF (IE00B60SWX25)](http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/de/etfs/source+euro+stoxx+50+ucits+etf+etf+IE00B60SWX25).